# Iterating over files with optional leading dots, without using shopt -s dotglob

Tags: bash

In a bash script, I'd like to list all files matching a string, including those with a leading dot.

E.g.

```
    ls -A
```

gives me

```
    .bla.0  .bla.1  bla.2   bla.3
```

and I'd like to have an expression of the sort

```
    for f in <whatgoeshere?>${pat}* ; do
      <something with $f>
    done
```

I have tried to use

```
    shopt -s extglob
```

and some form of ?(.)bla* and ?(\.)bla*, but to no avail.

I could use

```
    shopt -s dotglob
```

but I was wondering, if there's a way to specify the pattern without using that.

This would work, but is not very elegant:

```
    for f in `shopt -s dotglob ; ls -A *${pat}*` ; do echo $f; done
```

Comment: in the case you presented, you could use rename to normalize the naming to always (not) contain the leading dot.

Comment: True, but those files get generated by many parallel rsync sessions and I need to tally up the total size transferred so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pat=bla

for i in .${pat}* ${pat}*; do
    echo $i
done
```

Comment: Beautifully simple! This'll work. I forgot that you could just list anything between 'in' and ';'. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @StefanLudwig: I found couple of issues with this approach. **1)** If you don't have any file name starting with `bla` in your current directory then it will list `bla*` **2)** If you have a file `..bla` that won't be found with this script. You may not encounter them if you don't run into 2 scenarios but it is just fyi.

Comment: **1)** nullglob **2** that was not in the assignment however could be  fixed by using .*${pat}*

Answer (score 2):

You can replace your `ls -A` command with `find` with `-regex` switch like this:

```
while read f; do echo $f; done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -regex ".*${pat}.*")
```

Comment: Bonus points for this generic solution. I was looking for something without an external tool, but this works for any kind of weird patterns. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need extglobs.  Just use something like this:

```
for f in {.,}${pat}* ; do
    [[ $f == "." || $f == ".." ]] && continue
    echo $f
done
```

*Update:*

If you anticipate files with spaces in the name, go with the `find` based solution.

Comment: This will work with space-containing file names. You'll just need to quote the expansion of `$f`. For POSIX compatibility, you can also simply use `.$pat* $pat*` (which I see is the solution yaccz posted).